# validation rule issue its not working as expected

Tags: validation-rule

Below is the validation rule

```
(TEXT(Full_Care_Confirmed__c)) == 'Yes'
&&
(
((ISPICKVAL(CPQ_Order_Type__c,'Corporate-Full Care Equipment Domestic'))
||
ISPICKVAL(CPQ_Order_Type__c,'Corporate-Full Care International')
||
ISPICKVAL(CPQ_Order_Type__c,'Corporate-Full Care Demo Equipment Accept')
||
ISPICKVAL(CPQ_Order_Type__c,'Canada-Full Care Equipment')))
```

IF full care confirmed picklist field is set to YES then CPQ_Order_Type__c picklist value should be any of the above

Answer (score 0):

Validation rules trigger an error when the result is TRUE. This means you need to invert the logic with the NOT operator.

```
ISPICKVAL(Full_Care_Confirmed__c,'Yes')
&& NOT(
ISPICKVAL(CPQ_Order_Type__c,'Corporate-Full Care Equipment Domestic')    ||
ISPICKVAL(CPQ_Order_Type__c,'Corporate-Full Care International')         ||
ISPICKVAL(CPQ_Order_Type__c,'Corporate-Full Care Demo Equipment Accept') ||
ISPICKVAL(CPQ_Order_Type__c,'Canada-Full Care Equipment')
)
```

Comment: i have added and tested it but when we select any of the above value like Corporate-Full Care Equipment Domestic it  is also throwing error.

Comment: Snippet which i have edited TEXT(SBQQ__Quote__r.CPQ_Subsidiary__c )== 'VTI NA' 
&& 
$User.Avoid_Validation_Rules__c = false 
&& 
ISPICKVAL(Full_Care_Confirmed__c,'Yes') 
&& NOT( 
ISPICKVAL(CPQ_Order_Type__c,'Corporate-Full Care Equipment Domestic') || 
ISPICKVAL(CPQ_Order_Type__c,'Corporate-Full Care International') || 
ISPICKVAL(CPQ_Order_Type__c,'Corporate-Full Care Demo Equipment Accept') || 
ISPICKVAL(CPQ_Order_Type__c,'Canada-Full Care Equipment') 
)

Answer (score 0):

You can not set the value of a field using [Validation Rule](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/validation_rules). The purpose of validation rule is to show error when some condition matches. For your requirement , you will need to use [Process Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation/process_builder) or [Workflow rule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_examples.htm&type=5)

Comment: I am not setting the value here. I prompting user to check the value in pick list field value correctly.